# How to test a header property in .netcore-3.0?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, asp.net-core-3.0

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#examine-the-posttodoitem-create-method), the following adds a Location header to the response.

```
// POST: api/TodoItems
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> PostTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem)
{
    _context.TodoItems.Add(todoItem);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    //return CreatedAtAction("GetTodoItem", new { id = todoItem.Id }, todoItem);
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTodoItem), new { id = todoItem.Id }, todoItem);
}
```

In Xunit, how should I write the Assert part of the unit-test in order to test the value of the Location header?

```
[Fact]
public async Task Posting_A_ValidTodoItem_Creates_LocationHeader()
{

    // Arrange
    //...

    // Act
    var result = await.controller.PostToDoItem(toDoItem)

    // Assert
    //???
}
```

Testing the status code and response body has been straight forward, but I haven't been able to test the header yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can test something like this,

```cs
// Assert
Assert.NotNull(controller.Response.Header["Location"]);
```